# Select from table where both columns have same value

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have the code that selects all articles. What I am doing is, I think, wrong. I am selecting all values and then I am executing them.

```
Article::all()->each(function($article) {
         if ($article->created_at == $article->published_at && $article>published) {
             $article->update(['published_at' => null]);
         } 
     });
```

What I need to do is select only those articles that have the mentioned created_at and updated_at the same.
How could I do that on the database level?
I need sth like that:

```
Article::where('created_at', '=', 'published_at')->where('published')->get()->each(function($article) {
           $article->update(['published_at' => null]);
     }
});
```

This code sure does not work, its just for imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to search on the two columns for the one value:

```
Article::where(['created_at' => $date, 'updated_at' => $date ])->get();
```

Edit:

Use whereRaw for this

```
Article::whereRaw('created_at = updated_at')->get();
```

Comment: I know that, but the I cannot access `$date` variable. It is not set

Comment: Oh I gotcha, your question wasn't clear on that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah I admit it was not clear enough. I will try to be more clear next time, anyway, thanks, it works!(:

Answer (score 2):

edit your code

```
Article::all()->each(function($article) {
     if ($article->created_at == $article->published_at && $article->published) {
         $article->update(['published_at' => null]);
     } 
 });
```

Comment: Didn't you just write the same code that I already have? Your answer does not solve the problem.

Comment: No, That code has error $article>published ====> $article->published

Comment: oh, yes I see. I just made it up for example I did not run it. But it was not my point.